# Converting html input files data to base64 gives array length 0 but still the data is saved in that array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, filereader

I am trying to convert multiple input files from html input tag to base64 data and push it into an Array. I think the problem is with the reader.onload because the array length increments perfectly fine when I console it inside the onload event; but as soon as the console.log(array) is printed outside the onload, the length becomes 0 and the data is still printing.

```
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => {
         
         let files = e.target.files
           const formatFiles = []
         for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
           let reader = new FileReader();
           reader.readAsDataURL(files[i])
           reader.onload = (el) => {
             let data = {}
             data = {
               contentAttachment: {
                 contentType: reader.result.split("/")[1].split(";base64")[0],
                 data: reader.result.split("base64,")[1]
               }
             }
             formatFiles.push(data)
           }
         }
           console.log("formatFiles Length => ", formatFiles.length, " Data => ", formatFiles)
         setSelectedFiles(formatFiles)
       }} name="" id="" multiple />
```

Am I missing something about onload or FileReader ?

[image: Here, The array is printed outside the onload]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is related to the asynchronous behavior of the FileReader.
For good pratices, please, separate your html from javascript.

Correction:

```html
<input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" multiple>

<script>

const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
  const files = event.target.files;
  const promises = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i];

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (event) => {
        const data = {
          contentAttachment: {
            contentType: event.target.result.split("/")[1].split(";base64")[0],
            data: event.target.result.split("base64,")[1],
          },
        };
        resolve(data);
      };
      reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });

    promises.push(promise);
  }

  const formatFiles = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log("formatFiles Length => ", formatFiles.length, " Data => ", formatFiles);
  setSelectedFiles(formatFiles);
});

</script>
```